# Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid. XAF Update Model. CustomAttributeFormatException

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-core, xaf

When I try to update my Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml I get the error log below.
After reading [this post about the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153974/customattributeformatexception-binary-format-of-the-specified-custom-attribute) I wondered whether I have some mapping function defined incorrectly

For example my code uses

```
public static List<T> SqlQueryOfT<T>(string query, string connectionString, Func<DbDataReader, T> map, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    var entities = new List<T>();
    using var cn = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var command = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = cn;
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    foreach (var param in parameters)
        command.Parameters.Add(param);
    cn.Open();
    using var result = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (result.HasRows)
    {
        while (result.Read())
        {
            var r = map(result);
            entities.Add(r);
        }
    }
    cn.Close();
    return entities;
}
```

Could the error be because I call this function with an incorrect mapping?
I call this kind of function a lot so I am wondering how to identify which mapping is the problem.

I do have the DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.NetCorePackage.2022 Extension installed Although [the help](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/400081/installation-upgrade-version-history/visual-studio-integration/designers-troubleshooting-guide?utm_source=DevExpress&utm_medium=ModelEditor&utm_campaign=XAF&utm_content=XAF_ModelEditor_Troubleshooting&p=net6#model-editor-issues) does not mention the .2022
[image: Extension name]

Model.DesignedDiffs.log contains:

```
Type:       CustomAttributeFormatException
Message:    Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid.
Data:       0 entries
Stack trace:

   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeEncodedArgument.ParseAttributeArguments(IntPtr pCa, Int32 cCa, CustomAttributeCtorParameter[]& CustomAttributeCtorParameters, CustomAttributeNamedParameter[]& CustomAttributeTypedArgument, RuntimeAssembly assembly)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData..ctor(RuntimeModule scope, MetadataToken caCtorToken, ConstArray& blob)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tkTarget)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributesInternal(RuntimeType target)
   at System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.GetNullableContext(MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.GetNullabilityInfo(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type type, NullableAttributeStateParser parser, Int32& index)
   at System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.Create(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableConventionBase.IsNonNullableReferenceType(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableNavigationConvention.IsNonNullable(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionNavigation navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableNavigationConvention.ProcessNavigation(IConventionNavigationBuilder navigationBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableNavigationConvention.ProcessNavigationAdded(IConventionNavigationBuilder navigationBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnNavigationAdded(IConventionNavigationBuilder navigationBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnNavigationAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelConfigurationBuilder.CreateModelBuilder(ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreTypeInfoSource.CollectEntityTypes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreTypeInfoSource.GetEntityTypes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreExportedTypeHelper.CollectTypes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreExportedTypeHelper.get_CollectedTypes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreExportedTypeHelper.IsExportedTypeCore(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.CachedExportedTypeHelper.IsExportedType(Type type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ExportedTypeHelpers.IsExportedType(Type type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ModuleBase.IsExportedType(Type type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ModuleHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CollectRequiredExportedTypes>b__0(ITypeInfo t)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.TypeInfo.DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.ITypeInfo.GetRequiredTypes(Predicate`1 filter)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ModuleHelper.CollectRequiredExportedTypes(IEnumerable`1 exportedTypes, Predicate`1 isExportedType)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ModuleBase.GetExportedTypes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.<>c.<CollectDomainComponents>b__23_1(ModuleBase m)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.CollectMany(ModuleList modules, Func`2 method)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.<CollectDomainComponents>b__23_0()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.TypesCache.GetTypes(String group, Func`1 producer)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.CollectDomainComponents()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.LoadCore(ITypesInfo typesInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.Load(ITypesInfo typesInfo, Boolean loadTypesInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Utils.DesignerModelFactory.CreateModulesManager(ModuleBase module, String assembliesPath, List`1 additionalModules, ISecurityStrategyBase securityInstance, Action initializeTypeInfoSources)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Utils.DesignerModelFactory.CreateModulesManager(ModuleBase module, String assembliesPath, Action initializeTypeInfoSources)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditor.ModelLoader.LoadModel(ITypeDiscoveryService typeDiscoveryService, String targetDiffFileName, IDisposable& obj, ILogger logger)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditor.ModelEditorFormController.CreateModelEditorController()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditor.ModelEditorFormController.Init()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditorServer.ServerHost.CreateNewModelEditor(String fileName, ModelEditorInfo meInfo, String projectUniqueName, Dictionary`2 settings, String frameworkVersion)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditorServer.ServerHost.<>c__DisplayClass66_0.<OpenModelEditor>b__1()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelEditorServer.UiRunner.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunOnUIThreadCore>b__0(Object _)
    InnerException is null
```

[Update]

The problem seems to be todo with ConditionalAppearance.

After reducing the number of classes in DBContext I now have

Error:

```
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException: 'FontStyle' property specified was not found.
 ---> System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException: 'FontStyle' property specified was not found.
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.<>c.<GetOwnAttributes>b__5_0(Type key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.GetOwnAttributes(Type type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.InitAttributes(TypeInfo typeInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.TypeInfo.EnsureAttributesCore()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.EnsureAttributes()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseInfo.FindAttributes[AttributeType](Boolean recursive)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.BaseTypeInfoSource.CalcTypeVisibility(TypeInfo typeInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.NonPersistentTypeInfoSource.InitTypeInfo(TypeInfo info)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.NonPersistentTypeInfoSource.RegisterEntity(Type type)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.TypesInfo.RegisterEntity(Type entityType)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.TypesInfo.RegisterEntities(IEnumerable`1 types)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.LoadDomainComponents(ITypesInfo typesInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.LoadTypesInfo(ITypesInfo typesInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ApplicationModulesManager.Load(ITypesInfo typesInfo, Boolean loadTypesInfo)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Utils.DesignerModelFactory.CreateModulesManager(ModuleBase module, String assembliesPath, List`1 additionalModules, ISecurityStrategyBase securityInstance, Action initializeTypeInfoSources)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Utils.DesignerModelFactory.CreateModulesManager(ModuleBase module, String assembliesPath, Action initializeTypeInfoSources)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelUpdater.UpdateModel(ProjectReference projectReference)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.ModelUpdater.UpdateModel(ModelUpdater modelUpdater, ProjectReference projectReference, OutputWindowPane outputWindow)
Update failed
```

[Update]

The following attributes on a Non Persistent business object will cause the FontStyle error

```
[DomainComponent]
[Appearance("ToDoGreen", FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular, BackColor = "#D9EAD3", TargetItems = "*", Criteria = "true", Context = "ListView")]
```

Comment: I can now reproduce the CustomAttributeFormatException 'FontStyle' error by putting the [DomainComponent] attribute on a NonPersistent Business Object

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to reproduce the problem in a new XAF 23.1.6 Winforms EFCore project.

For now In my development project I can work around the issue by not having an appearance attribute on a business class that sets the font style.

In my code the following will cause the error when I update the model.

```
[DomainComponent]
[Appearance("IsPromisedApp", Criteria = "IsValid", FontStyle = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)]

public class ApplicationUser : PermissionPolicyUser, IObjectSpaceLink, ISecurityUserWithLoginInfo
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base() { UserLogins = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationUserLoginInfo>(); }
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC.Aggregated]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<ApplicationUserLoginInfo> UserLogins { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsValid { get; set; }
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ISecurityUserLoginInfo> IOAuthSecurityUser.UserLogins => UserLogins.OfType<ISecurityUserLoginInfo>();

    ISecurityUserLoginInfo ISecurityUserWithLoginInfo.CreateUserLoginInfo(
        string loginProviderName,
        string providerUserKey)
    {
        ApplicationUserLoginInfo result = ((IObjectSpaceLink)this).ObjectSpace
            .CreateObject<ApplicationUserLoginInfo>();
        result.LoginProviderName = loginProviderName;
        result.ProviderUserKey = providerUserKey;
        result.User = this;
        return result;
    }
}
```

If I omit the Font-Style from the Appearance or move the Appearance attribute to be on a property then I can update the model without an error.

Comment: XAF 23.2.3 solves this.